# In right $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle A=90^\circ$ and $\angle B=30^\circ$, is the incenter closer to $A$ or to the midpoint of $BC$?

Tags: geometry

I would like to ask if anyone could help me solve the following task.

> In $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle A=90^\circ$ and $\angle B = 30^\circ$, the circle is inscribed with center point $S$ and the point $D$ is located in the center of side $BC$. The aim is to compare the lengths of $AS$ and $DS$. Which is longer? I would like the procedure or proof of execution.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Note that S is the incenter, which is the intersection of all three angle bisectors. Since you know all 3 angles of the triangle, it is trivial to locate S.

Comment: So what point is S closer to A or D.

Comment: If CD+DB and $\beta=30^o$ then AC=CD and triangles ACS and CSD are congruent so AS=SD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\beta=30° → \quad CB=2\,CA \quad\quad → \quad\;CD=CA$

$SC \text{ is angle bisector of ∠ACB }\, → ∠SCA = ∠SCD$

Since $SC = SC$, we have SAS congruence

$$ΔSCA ≅ ΔSCD → AS=DS$$

Answer (score 1):

The fact that angle $\beta=30°$ implies that triangle $ABC$ is a half-equilateral triangle with side length $CB$. In particular :

$$CA = \tfrac12 CB = CD.$$

Therefore $ACD$ is an isosceles triangle.

$S$, being the incenter of $ABC$, lies on the angle bissector of angle $C$, which is known to be as well the altitude of triangle $ACD$ dropped from $C$. As the altitude of an isosceles triangle is a line of symmetry, and as this symmetry swaps line segments $SA$  and $SD$, they have the same length.